# How does one arrive at this condition (sodium band structure via WS cellular method)?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

(This question is, essentially, about how equation (11.12) in Ashcroft and Mermin obtains, but I here provide context for those who don't have the book at their disposal.)

In the cellular method, one solves the $H$ eigenvalue equation ("time-independent Schrodinger equation") in one primitive cell and then stitches the solution together using Bloch's theorem and the continuity requirements on all wavefunctions. This latter stitching leads to 2 boundary conditions to the solution in a given unit cell:

$$\psi(\mathbf{r}) = e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\psi(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})$$
and
$$\hat{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{r}) \cdot \nabla \psi(\mathbf{r}) = e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\hat{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R}) \cdot \nabla\psi(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{R})$$
where $\hat{\mathbf{n}}(\mathbf{r})$ denotes the local normal to the unit cell.

Now Ashcroft and Mermin describe how this method is applied (was applied by Wigner and Seitz) to the calculation of the energies at $\mathbf{k} = \mathbf{0}$ of the valence bands of sodium. In so doing, they argue, it is possible to take $\psi(\mathbf{r}) \propto \chi_0 (r)$ after the enforcing of spherical symmetry by way of deciding to solve the problem instead in a sphere of radius $r_0$ such that the sphere has the same volume as the primitive cell. They then say that this fact means that the above *two* boundary conditions reduce to the requirement that the derivative of $\chi_0$ vanishes on this spherical boundary,
$$\chi_0' (r_0) = 0,$$
but I cannot see how this obtains. Can anyone point me in the right direction?